# How to replace columns based on another column (matching parent id with id) python

Tags: python

I have a dataset that looks like this

| ID | TITLE | PARENT_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tom | NaN |
| 2 | Lisa | 1 |
| 3 | Lecy | 1 |
| 4 | Ann | NaN |
| 5 | John | NaN |
| 6 | Lana | 4 |

If Lisa's PARENT_ID is 1, then her parent is Tom. If tom has NaN parent_id, means he is not child, he is parent. So that,
I need it to look like this:

| ID | TITLE | PARENT_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tom | NaN |
| 2 | Lisa | Tom |
| 3 | Lecy | Tom |
| 4 | Ann | NaN |
| 5 | John | NaN |
| 6 | Lana | Ann |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use map

```
df['PARENT_ID_FINAL']=df['ID'].map(dict(zip(df['ID'],df['TITLE'])))
```